# PHP Building Dynamic WHERE Filter Out Column Names

Tags: php, arrays

Building a search engine for use on several of my sites, I give it a query and it builds the WHERE using the fields in the query. Since most queries that the site uses have a few column names in common that do not need to be searched, I've coded a filter for those in ***return*** and it all works well but now I want to pass into it an array containing names of other column names to not use when building the WHERE and am unsure how to do so. I'm probably trying to make it more difficult than it actually is so what should I do?

This code is actually a snippet from a much larger function but should be sufficient for the purposes of this question.

```
$HideFields = "BaseMarque, DateUpdated, LinkPage, LinkPath, AdminPage";

$HideFields = ($HideFields && !is_array($HideFields)) ? csv2Array($HideFields) : "";

$queryField = DBConnect($querySQL,"Select",$siteDB,"assoc");
$columns = array_keys($queryField);

$Where = 'WHERE ' . implode("\nAND ", array_map(function ($keyword) use ($columns) {
    return "\n(" . implode(' OR ', array_map(function ($column) use ($keyword) {
        return "\n`$column` LIKE '%$keyword%'";
    }, array_filter($columns, function ($column) {

            /* if (isset($HideFields)) {
                $column .= array_diff_key($columns, array_flip($HideFields));
            } */

            if (is_array($HideFields)) {
                foreach ($HideFields as $b) {
                    $column !== $b;
                }
            }

        return $column !== 'ID' && $column !== 'Deleted' && $column !== 'ShowPage';
    }))) . "\n)";
}, $keywords));
```

Comment: I am not able to provide an answer as of now but by the looks of it you are using concatenation and if any of the concatenated data has user input then this query is vulnerable to sql-injection. Just thought I'd convey it. PS: Fix would be to use prepared statements.

Comment: Good advice but there are a half-dozen sites sharing the code so changing it all would be a major undertaking and there is nothing on any of them where injection would be more than an inconvenience. Anyway, the concatenation you mentioned is in a bit of code that is remarked out as it didn’t work.

Comment: SQL-Injection scenarios should ideally be fixed ASAP. One could always write an equivalent wrapper that transparently handles the scenario. With regard to the question itself, assuming I understood it correctly, to skip few columns in the 'where' clause one option would be to use an array of columns to be skipped and check for same while building the query. Java has `list` and `set` data-structures. PHP I guess has `array`. You could try not of `in_array` function.

Comment: To the matter at hand, the list of columns to be skipped is already an array and that's exactly what I am trying to do but am not sure how to implement it in the existing code. I can hard-code them in the return as I did with a few common column names but I need to be able to do it more dynamically on others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be simple as I thought it would be. Also, the code had been written long ago and I didn't notice that there was a small function in it so it wasn't even getting the $HideFields value until I added it as a global within the function. If I decide I have a lot of time on my hands and want to convert all these sites to PDO and/or prepared statements, I'll post separately.

```
$Where = 'WHERE ' . implode("\nAND ", array_map(function ($keyword) use ($columns) {
    return "\n(" . implode(' OR ', array_map(function ($column) use ($keyword) {
        return "\n`$column` LIKE '%$keyword%'";
    }, array_filter($columns, function ($column) {
        global $HideFields;
        return $column !== 'ID' && $column !== 'Deleted' && $column !== 'ShowPage' && !in_array($column,$HideFields);
    }))) . "\n)";
}, $keywords));
```